# What can I use to cover broken cut baseboard angle?

Tags: baseboard

I've tried to replace my wood baseboard; I cut it without 45° angles so now the final result isn't nice.

Does some angle cover exist that I can use ?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Imagine you are thinking of something thin like shelving paper so you do not need to remove the baseboards again, instead of a corner shape piece of baseboard where you need to cut the baseboards back some.

Comment: I would guess you are talking about protruding corners not inset corners (pictures would help). I have seen metal caps on corners that got damaged but they would be expensive and if your skill set and tool set is limited to the point of butt joints this may be beyond your capability.  I would remove them add a section and make proper joints it will take more time but it can be salvaged with some time and effort.

Comment: @EdBeal That comment sounds like a good answer.

Comment: I see a couple of possibilities matching the above corner and bringing it down or using the piece on the right miter cut both sides then cut the left board and put the piece in , then a new piece will be needed on the right, that’s not a fancy cut just a rolled edge a brushed brown over white would be my guess but matching at a 90 is not as critical an the spliced in section  it would be this or a repaint as that looks like MDF or fiberboard with a paper surface so it can’t be sanded but it can be painted over, I may be wrong on the material but those are the options other than a metal corner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Baseboard corner blocks (or "plinths") are commonly used in higher-end homes. You may find one that works, or you can make one of your own with the right stain. However, they aren't magic beans and still require clean, precise cuts to look nice.

[image]

<sub>[image source](https://www.lowes.com/pd/EverTrue-1-1165-in-x-6-75-in-Interior-White-Hardwood-Outside-Corner-Baseboard-Moulding-Block/3383566)</sub>

Comment: Nice, but if you do one, you have to do them all

Comment: Not true at all. A simplified plinth that just fixes this one problem would be completely acceptable.

Comment: would it not interfere with the edge board on the top

Comment: Not if it fits under it. :P

Comment: what are the dimensions, and. how do you mount it

Comment: Where are you going with this? It fits what it needs to fit and looks like you want it to look. What else is there to say?

Comment: I am actually considering it, so just wanted to know

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any sort of pre-fabricated corner piece that you could use to cover that gap in the corner, since usually installations aren't done with a gap like that to begin with. If you know someone who works in metal, they might be able to make something for you, but it's likely that it would get bent by the first thing that bumps into the corner.

You *could* extend the corner bead down to the floor. It looks like it would just about touch the piece of baseboard on the left and you could trim back the baseboard on the right to match. This would be *unusual*, as usually the corner bead doesn't go all the way to the floor, but stops at the baseboard, but you wouldn't have to replace the baseboard. If you do this, you may want/need to have other corners in the house modified to match, since just one that doesn't match would really stand out.

If you don't want to do that (again, it would be unusual looking, but you could claim it was intentional as a distinctive design touch and make a conversation piece out of it :D ), you'll have to replace both pieces of baseboard since you've cut them too short. With some skills, it would probably be possible to cut the longer piece (on the left) back a bit and fill in a short piece to go to the corner, and replace the short piece on the right, however, you probably don't have the skills yet to do that and make it look really good.

Frankly, just making a nice tight 45° miter in the corner is a difficult skill and one I'm still working on, so there is no offense intended by that last statement. Getting tight joints is a skill and skills take time to develop.

Comment: Even an inexpensive miter box and a hand miter saw can make high quality 45’s and that is all that is needed on the corner and to extend a short cut, many pros will add a foot or 2 so the splice is not noticeable but it can be done fairly inexpensive and with accuracy.

Comment: 45s not too hard, finding perfect 90 degree corners another thing.

Answer (score 1):

Take the left over from baseboard and cut 2 pice.

Cut them at 45 Dgr as shown in the drawing.

[image: cut]

This can be perfectly accomplished with this simple tool. It might take some head scratching to figure it out how to cut. Think before cutting.

[image: cutting tool]

Test fit them together, and if satisfied glue them together.

**Getting the right measurement might be tricky.**

Here is some help

[image: rulers]

Take 2 rulers or flat aproximatly 1 inch wide, 1/4 thick boards.

First lay them flat against the wall. Mark where they cross and without removing measure left and right (to get the A).

Now repeat but lay them flat against the baseboards. Measure to get B.

Cut the new baseboards in 45 dgr as above.

Now transfer the A and B to new baseboard.

B is the total length of the new baseboard parts.

Alternatively Using the B only cut a baseboard length, then cut the 45 on the correct side.